# IE8 shows 404 error message in ASP.NET MVC areas if "show friendly HTTP error messages" is checked

Tags: asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer-8, http-status-code-404, asp.net-mvc-areas

I have an interesting behavior in IE8 if "show friendly HTTP error messages" is checked in the advanced internet options. Maybe IE7 too, I didn't tested this dinosaur. But in works in all other browsers like IE9 and greater, Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari...

The IE8 worked well with this ASP.NET MVC 4 Application expect in a single area, which is a separate password protected area in this application. The Authentication works really fine.

If I try to call an Action this area the IE8 shows the View for very short moment and than it shows the "friendly" 404 error message. If I uncheck the "show friendly HTTP error messages" in the advanced internet options, all works fine.

I don't know why IE8 is doing this. Maybe there is a HTTP header which the IE8 can't handle. What do you think? What is the possible reason for this behavior?

Thanks
Juergen

Comment: As we both know, ASP.NET MVC runs on the server and IE8 is a client which does not care about anything going on on the server side. The only thing that matters is what the server sends over the wire.

Did you check what happens on the client side when the page gets called by using the IE Developer Tools (F12)?

If that does not help, remove anything from the page - stylesheets, images and especially scripts - till the call does not end in a 404 anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I didn't get any 404 of an resources in the IE Developer tools, neither in any other browser. This is why I think it's possibly a kind of redirection http header with can't be handled by IE8. But I will try your suggestion tomorrow, maybe it helps...

Comment: Thanks for that hint. It was a wrong linked behavior in one of the CSS files

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in the comment of asp_net (view the comments above)

> remove anything from the page - stylesheets, images and especially scripts - till the call does not end in a 404 anymore

I checked all the resources and found a wrong linked behavior in one of my CSS files